# Errors with regexr and regexm

Tags: stata

When I run the following:

```
replace rating = regexr(rating,"(","")
```

I get the error below:

> regexp: unterminated ()

How can I resolve this?

Note that I get the same error if I try to use `regexm()`.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please up-vote it with the upper arrow and accept it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce your problem as follows:

```
clear 

input str12 foo
"nick"
"tom (amanda"
end

. replace foo = regexr(foo,"(","")

regexp: unterminated ()
regexp: unterminated ()
(0 real changes made)
```

The solution is to include an escape character before the left parenthesis in the function:

```
. replace foo = regexr(foo,"\(","")
(1 real change made)

. list

     +------------+
     |        foo |
     |------------|
  1. |       nick |
  2. | tom amanda |
     +------------+
```

Comment: Why the regular expression syntax is wrong perhaps deserves a comment. In the context of a regular expression function, which is what we have here, the parenthesis `(` has special meaning as grouping characters and so must be paired. If you want, as you do, the parenthesis to be taken literally, you have to say so with an escape character, as in the answer above. This is not a bug; it's entirely standard for such machinery. Note that `subinstr(rating, "(", "", .)` would work fine.